# Docker, WSL2 & vs code - bad git/ssh path

Tags: dockerfile, vscode-remote, wsl-2

I set up my WSL2, Docker and vs code environment this weekend.

I am finding an issue when attempting to use git:

```
root@bb7f765df0d6:/var/www/html# git clone git@github.com:hsimah/my-repo.git
Cloning into 'my-repo'...
fatal: cannot run C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM wordpress:latest
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends apt-utils dialog 2>&1 \
    && apt-get -y install git \
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && apt-get clean -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=dialog
```

If I remove the Dockerfile install of git and run `apt-get update && apt-get install git` from my container there is no issue. In this case git uses my host ssh keys (loaded via ssh-agent service on Windows) and can pull and push both via terminal or vs code itself.

There are no errors or warnings in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I posted a few minutes too soon.

I checked the git config and VS Code was pulling my Windows config into the workspace, it's a known issue.

Unblocking answer is to change this to your ssh location (`/usr/bin/ssh`):
`core.sshcommand=C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe`